# Access Violation in TeeChart

Tags: activex, teechart

Below code gives me access violation. Can anyone help me with  this.

```
for(long i = nTools-1; i > 0 ; i--)
{
    if(m_spGraph.GetTools().GetItems(i).GetToolType() == 25 && m_spGraph.GetTools().GetItems(i).GetAsRectangle().GetAllowDrag() == TRUE)  // Rectangle tool
    {
        m_spGraph.GetTools().Delete(i);
    }
}
```

Thanks
Akshay

Answer (score 1):

In VB6, if I run this and then I open an Editor I see 5 Rectangle tools and 5 Annotation tools:

```
  TChart1.AddSeries scBar
  TChart1.Series(0).FillSampleValues 8

  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 0 To 9
    If (i Mod 2 = 0) Then
      TChart1.Tools.Add tcRectangle
    Else
      TChart1.Tools.Add tcAnnotate
    End If
  Next i
```

Then, If I run this and I open the editor again after it, I only see the 5 Annotation tools:

```
  For i = TChart1.Tools.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If (TChart1.Tools.Items(i).ToolType = 25 And TChart1.Tools.Items(i).asRectangle.AllowDrag) Then
      TChart1.Tools.Delete i
    End If
  Next i
```

So it seems to work fine for me here.
Have you tried it with different TeeChart ActiveX builds? Have you obtained different results with each them?

Please, edit your question adding an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so we can reproduce the problem here and try to figure if there's a problem in your code or in the component.